# Disable going back in react-native using react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have been a lot of time searching and trying different stuff to disable going back once the "user" is logged in but it seams that NavigationActions does not work. This is the code:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const actionToDispatch = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate('DrawerNavigator')] // Array!
  })

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }


  render() {

    return (
        <RkAvoidKeyboard
        style={styles.screen}
        onStartShouldSetResponder={ (e) => true}
        onResponderRelease={ (e) => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <Button title="Complete Login" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.dispatch(actionToDispatch)}/>
          </View>
      </RkAvoidKeyboard>
    );
  }
}
```

I shrinked a little bit the code. What happens is that the dispatch actions does not work. And also I get the error: undefined is not a function(evaluating '_reactNavigation.NavigationActions .......) so it does not even compile. I have the last version of React-navigation(2.12.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `reset` action is not inside `NavigationActions`, so you have to change your `NavigationActions.reset` to `StackActions.reset` ([docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)).

What I do in that case is to `StackActions.replace` instead of `NavigationActions.navigate`. What [`replace`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#replace) do is like unmount current view and mount the given one, so when user wants to `goBack()` from first screen (logged in) it quits the app instead of navigating back to `Login`.